# AddJoin_management function from GPTool not working. Any examples of the usage of this function in ArcGIS Pro SDK?

Tags: attribute-joins, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have a feature class using which I create a Layer:

```
  featurelayerNew = await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
  { var lcp = new FeatureLayerCreationParams(featureClass);
    var featureLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<FeatureLayer> 
    (lcp, ActiveMap);
  return featureLayer;});
```

I retrieve the table to be joined from the Database:

```
public static async Task<Table> LoadSqlTable(string fields, string fromTableName, string whereCondition, string resultTableName)
{
 Table table = null;
 DatabaseConnectionProperties connectionProperties = new 
 DatabaseConnectionProperties(EnterpriseDatabaseType.Oracle)
 { AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.DBMS,
   User = AuthenticateUser.User,
   Password = AuthenticateUser.Password,
   Database = AuthenticateUser.Datasource,
   Instance = AuthenticateUser.Datasource,
 };
 table =  await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
 { 
  using (Database database = new Database(connectionProperties))
  {
   QueryDescription queryDescription = 
   database.GetQueryDescription("SELECT * FROM " + fromTableName + " 
   where " + whereCondition, resultTableName);
   Table dbtable = database.OpenTable(queryDescription);
   return dbtable;
   }
 });

 return table;
}
```

To the Layer i join the Table using the GPTool AddJoin function:

```
public static async Task<bool> JoinTableToLayerWithGP(FeatureLayer 
   layerToJoin, Table table, string sJoinFeldL, string sJoinFeldT)
  {
   try
   {
         var argsAddJoin = Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(layerToJoin, sJoinFeldL, tableToJoin, sJoinFeldT, "KEEP_ALL");
    var gpResult = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("AddJoin_management", argsAddJoin);
    
    var messages = string.IsNullOrEmpty(gpResult.ReturnValue) ? $@"Error in gp tool: {gpResult.ErrorMessages}" : $@"Ok: {gpResult.ReturnValue}";
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     errorMessage = ex.Message;
     return false;
    }
  });
 }
}
return true;
}
```

There are no errors in this function call. I am getting the name of the Layer as the Return value of gpResult. But I don't see the changes. Am I missing something?